# Is it OK to mark a question as a duplicate where the question and solution is similar, but about different topics?

Tags: discussion

[This question on filetypes for Markdown](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/221/open-md-files-as-markdown) is close to being closed as a duplicate of this 
question on the [.sage/Python extension type](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/61/setting-up-ft-according-to-the-file-extension). To be fair, both the theme of the question (associating a filetype with an extension) and the answers are very similar.

Is it OK for this type of duplicate to be "closed as a duplicate"? Should we be marking them as such?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, mark them as duplicate.

A question will be put on hold, **but not** removed. People still end up there through internet searches, and the like.

So we could have, for example:

- How do I tell Vim to recognize `*.foo` files as a `*.bar` file?

Which then may have the duplicates:

- How do I open `.md` files as Markdown?
- How do I open `.sage` files as Python?
- ...etc...

Putting a question "on hold" only prevents new answers, it does *not* prevent upvoting or editing of the existing questions.

Having *one* canonical question like this means we can have one (or a few) very good and extensive answers on that question, while the *How do I open `.md` files as Markdown?* will usually be answered with just a snippet of code...

Comment: This is the way to go when you've got several question potentials that are all the *same problem*, just looking from different angles. It helps that if you do have some such canonical question on file extensions for example, that when you close a newcomer's question as a duplicate of it, help explain the action in comments so that they understand why you're "closing" their question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

In terms of maintaining a resource for people faced with the same problems, having both discussions is useful.

Comment: They are both useful, that's why questions marked as duplicate are not deleted, but *put on hold*.